# How does cloakcoin determine valid transactions?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I recently read the enigma white paper but I'm having a hard time figuring out how the network reaches consensus of valid transactions if the inputs and outputs are scrambled. How does the blockchain reflect who's account gets incremented and deincremented with these scrambled transactions. And how does the blockchain record account balances without giving away transaction histories.